# Neatly draw two graphs with at least five vertices with the same degree sequence, where one is a tree and the other is not a tree.

Tags: graph-theory

Neatly draw two graphs with at least five vertices with the same degree sequence, where one is a tree and the other is not a tree.

Not sure how to draw the graphs. Would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

5-path $P_5$ (1,1,2,2,2)

Triangle $K_3$ (2,2,2) + $K_2$ (1,1)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you add two more edges to the graph on the right & get a different graph with the same degree sequence ?

[image]